# What does the yellow mean in this image from Virus Pathogen Resource?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, covid-19, sars-cov-2, molecular-genetics

What does the yellow mean in this image of a SARS (coronavirus) protease from the Virus Pathogen resource database? It's from https://www.viprbrc.org/brc/

[image: It's from https://www.viprbrc.org/brc/]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sulfur atoms are shown in yellow.

The molecular viewer that you use is JSMol (JMol ported to the web).

Atoms are colored by element: grey C, blue N, red O and yellow S.
If you wonder how other atoms would be colored, see JMol's [Default element colors, by periodic table](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/jscolors/).

Comment: Here's the direct link: https://www.viprbrc.org/brc/structureOperation.spg?accession=1P9S&decorator=corona&context=1583712525175

Comment: Another question I had was this: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/11612/are-there-any-sulfur-dioxide-molecules-in-this-structure Thanks

Comment: Looks like they're using the common [CPK method of colouring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPK_coloring), it's not unique for J(S)Mol.