# Are there any Sulfur Dioxide molecules in this structure?

Tags: protein-structure, molecular-genetics

Does the protein structure shown in the JSmol link have any Sulfur Dioxide molecules?

[image]

In the picture, the Sulfur element is yellow and Oxygen is red (see [here](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/jscolors/))

https://www.viprbrc.org/brc/structureOperation.spg?accession=1P9S&decorator=corona&context=1583712525175

Link to mmcif file (I have the VS Code plugin installed):

https://files.rcsb.org/view/1P9S.cif

Answer (score 2):

The answer, as provided in the comments by gilleain is No. The commenter wanted to know why I asked this. The reason is I heard sulfur dioxide as silent speech when thinking about antibodies that’s why I asked.

I searched the file https://files.rcsb.org/view/1P9S.cif for the SO2 molecule and didn't find it. I got confirmation in the comments of the question.

Would anyone be interested in an app that takes a .cif file of a molecule and allows you to search the file for any type of element or molecule in it? Would that help anyone with their research?

Comment: Sorry, I do not see the advantage. All three PDB databases allow ligand search by name, residue name or SMILES in the browser. The PDBe has a decent API (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/pdbe-rest-api), which gives info of which ligands are present, without downloading the structure. Furthermore, most instances of elements beyond the 6 of life are crystallisation artefacts, so it is way safer to search for enzymes that are expected to have more exotic elements, e.g. tungsten in a W-enzyme as seen in PDB:2W7Z.